# Docker gets stuck on building and other commands

Tags: docker

There's a very strange issue, the docker daemon can't response the building request and other commands like `docker info`. **But if I build image from an exist image Dockerfile `FROM some/exist/image`, it works well, `docker version` works well too.**  We have about 56 VMs to build images, the building command is just like this::

```
export DOCKER_HOST = '<my_host>'
docker build -t <tag> - < context.tar.gz
```

The client output below, it seems that it gets stuck on extrating:

```
[test]$ docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM busybox
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
7c9d20b9b6cd: Extracting  32.77kB/760.8kB
^C
```

But the cpu and memory are no problem, also there's still a lot of disk space.

```
[~]# top
top - 10:18:09 up 48 days, 20:20,  1 user,  load average: 1.00, 1.03, 1.05
Tasks: 167 total,   1 running, 166 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.7 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8006376 total,   603984 free,   612016 used,  6790376 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4192928 total,  4186560 free,     6368 used.  6749588 avail Mem
```

### Log:

I used systemctl to start dockerd and it's strange that I can't see recent log about dockerd, it seems that dockerd gets stuck from 16:04:08:

```
cat /var/log/messages|grep docker
2019-10-28 16:04:07 dockerd[1549]: time="2019-10-28T16:04:07+08:00" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/d584a3957292ac1d3edfea2ec57abcf2dbe79465f9bcd41183b0ccd9dac3bb01/shim.sock" debug=false pid=18014
2019-10-28 16:04:08 dockerd[1549]: time="2019-10-28T16:04:08+08:00" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=d584a3957292ac1d3edfea2ec57abcf2dbe79465f9bcd41183b0ccd9dac3bb01
2019-10-28 16:04:08 dockerd[1549]: time="2019-10-28T16:04:08.081553011+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
2019-10-28 19:15:00 dockerd[1549]: time="2019-10-28T19:15:00.826993765+08:00" level=error msg="Not continuing with pull after error: context canceled"
2019-10-28 19:17:49 dockerd[1549]: time="2019-10-28T19:17:49.216471516+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.38/build returned error: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF"
2019-10-28 19:42:18 dockerd[1549]: time="2019-10-28T19:42:18.954682094+08:00" level=error msg="Not continuing with pull after error: context canceled"
2019-10-28 19:51:51 dockerd[1549]: time="2019-10-28T19:51:51.611278576+08:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"
2019-10-28 19:52:03 dockerd[1549]: time="2019-10-28T19:52:03.076089163+08:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"
2019-10-28 19:55:41 dockerd[1549]: time="2019-10-28T19:55:41.605964950+08:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://xx/centos/manifests/6: no basic auth credentials"
2019-10-28 19:55:44 dockerd[1549]: time="2019-10-28T19:55:44.298856115+08:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://xx/centos/manifests/6: no basic auth credentials"
```

### Docker processes:

```
[~]# ps -ef|grep docker
root      1549     1  6 Oct09 ?        1-05:45:10 /usr/bin/dockerd
root      1557  1549  0 Oct09 ?        00:42:20 docker-containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
root      2574  1549  0 Oct09 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8090 -container-ip x.x.x.x -container-port 8080
root      2581  1557  0 Oct09 ?        00:00:41 docker-containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /opt/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/56e9432a55304bc61d284d3a9da15272d292c1493d33d4499e481a0d64ff53e4 -address /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/docker-containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
root     15630 15049  0 10:13 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto docker
```

### Docker version:

```
[~]$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a
 Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:23:03 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

### Proc Stack

```
[root@vm ~]# cat /proc/1549/stack
[<ffffffff810f8564>] futex_wait_queue_me+0xc4/0x120
[<ffffffff810f90d9>] futex_wait+0x179/0x280
[<ffffffff810fb1de>] do_futex+0xfe/0x5b0
[<ffffffff810fb710>] SyS_futex+0x80/0x180
[<ffffffff8169d53d>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

I’ve seen the github issue like https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/813 and https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12823 , but I can’t get a correct way to solve this.
How can I solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### System

```
Centos
Kernel: 3.10.0-514.41.1.el7 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: check if your files/directory have correct permissions. `"Handler for POST /v1.38/build returned error: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF"` this error can be cause of that. If a file have root owner, maybe dont have enouth permissions to be readed or executed. Check that.

Comment: @Schwarz54 Thanks for your comment, but it is not caused by this.

Comment: Are you using Docker for windows or linux ?

Comment: @MohitMutha It's Centos.

Comment: Can you provide the docker file? Even if mostly redacted? I suspect it's something wrong with what you're trying to build, primarily because in the systemd output, the BUILD post controller indicates it has an unexpected end of file. Might have an unterminated quote somewhere?

Comment: @Dockstar Actually, the Dockerfile for getting stuck is random, different tasks will be stuck randomly, but in most cases, they are successfully executed. The dockerd log after 19:15:00 should actually be caused by my forced termination of the daemon.

Answer (score 3):

Its hard to reproduce your problem. But here are some ideas, how you can solve the problem.

1. **dockerd has a bad state**
   Sometimes a restart via `systemctl restart dockerd` solves problems.
2. **dockerd is corrupted**
   I saw a problem of corrupted installation of docker. It leads to strange behaviors they never get 1:1 reproduced. Just reinstall docker on the maschine.
3. **other**
   Many other factors can produce this problem. Maybe there are problems with your centos. In one of your links, somebody discovered that a antivirus-system was the bad one (see https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/813#issuecomment-431031402).

Answer (score 0):

you should start docker daemon with debug mode, like

```
dockerd --debug
```

FYI, [configure and debug docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/)